# How to implement Conv3D on sequence of images?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am supposed to implement Conv3D on sequence of images. There are 72 images in the file and size of each image is (16,16,3) where 3 is the channel. Following is my code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

input_shape = (7,16,16,3) # 7 is the no. of images to be input to Conv3D at a time.
no_classes = 1
epoch = 7
verbosity = 1
learning_rate = 0.001

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(5,kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),padding ='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_uniform',input_shape=input_shape)) 
                 
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 3), padding= 'same'))
model.add(Conv3D(3,kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_uniform')) 
                 
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(no_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

# Fit data to model
history = model.fit(trainX, new_trainy,
        batch_size = 25,
        epochs = 7)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Epoch 1/7
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-92321d5fc5a8> in <module>()
     2 history = model.fit(trainX, new_trainy,
     3             batch_size = batch_size,
----> 4             epochs = epoch)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, 
batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, 
sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, 
validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, 
*args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, 
**kwds)
    869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    870       initializers = []
--> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    872     finally:
    873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, 
args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: 
disable=protected-access
--> 726             *args, **kwds))
    727 
    728     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in 
_get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2967       args, kwargs = None, None
   2968     with self._lock:
-> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2970     return graph_function
   2971 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in 
_maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3359 
   3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3363 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in 
_create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3204             arg_names=arg_names,
   3205             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3206             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3207         self._function_attributes,
   3208         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in 
func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, 
autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, 
capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, 
**kwds)
    632             xla_context.Exit()
    633         else:
--> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    635         return out
    636 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, 
**kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:754 train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:998 __call__
    input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:239 assert_input_compatibility
    str(tuple(shape)))

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 16, 16, 3)
```

trainX has the shape (72,16,16,3) where 72 is the number of images, (16,16) is the dimension of the image and 3 is the channel i.e, rgb

Can any one please help me to come out of this error. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got where I am making a mistake:

Each input to Conv3D must be a 4 dimensional data point. While in my case each data point in the dataset i.e, trainX is of shape(16,16,3) which is 3 dimensional. In order to have each data point of same shape i.e. 4D(7,16,16,3), I removed last 2 images from trainX so that number of images or data points (i.e. 70) in trainX is multiple of 7. Next, I reshaped trainX to 5D data.

Now there are 10 data points in trainX in which each data point is 4D (i.e. (7,16,16,3)).

That removed the error and my model executed perfectly.
Following is the code:

```
 new_trainX = trainX[:70,:,:,:]
 new_trainX2 = tf.reshape(new_trainX,shape = (10,7,16,16,3))
 
 # Fit data to model
        history = model.fit(new_trainX2, new_trainy,
                  batch_size = batch_size,
                  epochs = epoch)

   Here is the output:
   Epoch 1/7
   1/1 [==============================] - 1s 557ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000
   Epoch 2/7
   1/1 [==============================] - 0s 129ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000
   Epoch 3/7
   1/1 [==============================] - 0s 131ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000
   Epoch 4/7
   1/1 [==============================] - 0s 129ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000
   Epoch 5/7
   1/1 [==============================] - 0s 128ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000
   Epoch 6/7
   1/1 [==============================] - 0s 140ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000
   Epoch 7/7
   1/1 [==============================] - 0s 129ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: What was your `model.summary()`?